# Linear Optimization Problem in Python Doesn't Respect Constraints

Tags: python, scipy

I'm solving a linear optimization problem in Python using an optimization library. However, I'm having difficulties getting the problem to respect the specified constraints.

Here's my code:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
x1_bounds = (None, None)
c_2 = [1, 1]
a_2 = [[ 4.87892727e+01,  2.97284721e+02],
       [ 1.26013470e+07,  2.37672878e+08],
       [-2.48999371e-01, -1.77252972e+00],
       [-3.16435265e-01, -5.22468352e+00],
       [-9.00000000e-01,  1.00000000e-01],
       [ 1.00000000e-01, -9.00000000e-01],
       [ 2.00000000e-01, -8.00000000e-01],
       [-8.00000000e-01,  2.00000000e-01],
       [-1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]]
b_2 = [2000, 50000000, -1, -1.91, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, -0.06, 3.0, 0.3]

res = linprog(c_2, A_ub=a_2, b_ub=b_2, bounds=[x1_bounds, x1_bounds], method="interior-point")
```

The problem is that the constraints don't seem to be respected by the program. For example, one of the constraints is x1 * 1.26013470e+07 + x2 * 2.37672878e+08 < 50,000,000. However, the obtained result [1.93111699, 0.53921743] doesn't satisfy this constraint.

I've checked the a_2 matrix and the b_2 vector, but I can't identify the issue. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong in my code and how I can correct it to ensure the constraints are properly respected?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible from the code provided.  You have a much higher chance of getting help if it is...  You also didn't say what the result was, what the solver reported, etc., so there isn't much info here.  It may be possible that you are dealing with numerical error issues because the oddly constructed problem you present spans 10 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code per se, but your problem is infeasible as formulated. If you look at the result object, you'll see:

```
message: The algorithm terminated successfully and determined that the problem is infeasible.
 success: False
  status: 2
     fun: 2.4703344126866513
       x: [ 1.931e+00  5.392e-01]
     nit: 6
```

You will need to remove or modify some constraints for the problem to have a feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call into the interior point method; allow HiGHS to run.

Your last four constraints all need to be converted to bounds.

Your second constraint probably *should* be normalized, but that isn't your biggest problem.

Your third and fourth constraints each make the problem infeasible.

This runs, though it's impossible to say if this is domain-valid since two of the constraints have been commented out.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

a_2 = np.array((
    ( 4.87892727e+01,  2.97284721e+02),
    ( 1.26013470e+07,  2.37672878e+08),
    # (-2.48999371e-01, -1.77252972e+00),
    # (-3.16435265e-01, -5.22468352e+00),
    (-9.00000000e-01,  1.00000000e-01),
    ( 1.00000000e-01, -9.00000000e-01),
    ( 2.00000000e-01, -8.00000000e-01),
    (-8.00000000e-01,  2.00000000e-01),
))
b_2 = (
    2000,
    50_000_000,
    # -1,
    # -1.91,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
)

res = linprog(
    c=(1, 1), A_ub=a_2, b_ub=b_2,
    bounds=(
        (0.25, 3),
        (0.06, 0.3)
    ),
)
assert res.success, res.message
print('x =', res.x)
print('Evaluated bounds:')
print(a_2 @ res.x)
```

```
x = [0.25   0.0625]
Evaluated bounds:
[ 3.07776132e+01  1.80048916e+07 -2.18750000e-01 -3.12500000e-02
  0.00000000e+00 -1.87500000e-01]
```